# Is it possible to lose precision when only using multiplication and division of integers? How about using doubles?

Tags: java, integer, double, precision

In java, if we have an operation like below that only uses integers and multiplication and division, is it possible that `result` would not be equal to `int3` due to lose of precision?

```
Int int1, int2, int3 = some values
Double result = ((((int1 / int2) * int3)/ int3)* int2)
```

Edit:
What if we have `Double int1, int2, int3 = some values`?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in fact it most certainly wouldn't be as you are doing **Integer** arithmetic and this causes **truncation** - so, for example, `3/2` would be `1`.

Comment: Found this useful: [java-maximum-loss-of-precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470757/java-maximum-loss-of-precision-in-one-double-addition-subtraction)

Comment: Not really relevant here as you are doing `int` arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're performing division using integer operands, so yes, that's very likely to lose information. It's quite the same as losing *precision* in the same way that normal floating point arithmetic loses precision, but it's still information loss. It does every time the result isn't an exact integer.

For example:

```
int int1 = 1;
int int2 = 2;
int int3 = 3;

double result = (((int1 / int2) * int3) / int3) * int2;
```

... gives zero, because `int1 / int2` is zero.

Beyond that, there's then the possibility of overflow on the multiplication side of things.

Answer (score 1):

In java, any time you divide an int by another int you are risking loss of precision. So, the short answer to your question is yes. More info about integer division in this tutorial: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm